# Getting an OV code signing certificate without individual identity verification

Tags: java, code-signing

Upon looking into getting a new OV code signing certificate it appears that a new requirement from Comodo is the requesting individual needs to submit government ID, PLUS selfie photo for them to do biometrics, facial recognition, whatever.  I'm not sure what that has to do with validating an organization.  Anyway, are there any other code signing authorities that don't require this type of personal scrutiny?

Thanks,

I've done a search for other code signing authorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your organization has existed for more then 3 years, then take a look at SSL.com, their documentation states:

> For OV Code Signing certificates only, if the business or organization is less than three years old, a scan of the certificate requestor’s government-issued ID is also required.

Source: https://www.ssl.com/faqs/ssl-ov-validation-requirements/#ftoc-heading-2

The rest of the verification steps seem to be for the organization itself instead of the individual submitting the request.